# JavaScript, Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
values.map(value => {
    if (value.gse === gse) {
      return value.y
    }
  })
```

I need to map then return `value.y` only in the case of the `if` statement that I put in the example.
How can avoid the warning of `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function`, I mean, how should I correctly write that code? with a `return this` in case `value.gse !== gse` ?

Comment: Whats inside `values` and what results do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `filter`, and then `map`:

```
values.filter(value => values.gse === gse).map(value => value.y);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the idea (not my code, just cleaning some warnings)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with **reduce()**. Code will be like:

```
values.reduce((list, value) => {
    if(values.gse === gse) list.push(value.y);
    return list;
}, []);
```

Hope this helps :)